# Is it possible to run Android test Activities in the foreground?

Tags: android, testing

I am trying to test an Android application which interacts with another program over the network. I want to do this in a script format where I execute a command, verify the result on the other program, and then press a button to continue to the next command. So, I wrote a simple Activity to handle this. The problem is that all tests appear to be run in a hidden state; I can't see my Activity on screen, or in fact even see that my tests are running on the device under the app switcher. Is it possible to run a tested Activity in the foreground where I can interact with it, or can this not be done? I could put this into my main app but then I would have to hide it from users and figure out an obscure way to invoke it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve, can you please elaborate, maybe giving some examples?

Comment: Carlos, I am trying to run a test Activity and have it be visible in the foreground, where I can interact with it. Right now all the tests seem to run in a hidden mode and even though my Activity is waiting I cannot see it. I am using a real device (Motorola Xoom), not an emulator.